# Handling soap+msbin1 content type in Jmeter

Tags: web-services, wcf, jmeter, performance-testing

I am trying to use Jmeter for performance testing of a WPF app that uses WCF Web Service. I see that the service is using msbin1 encoding format. Hence i am no able to make out what the request parameters are. How to handle this in Jmeter

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the request you need to just add [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) and configure it to send [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header with the value of `soap-msbin1`. In order to send the actual payload you can use i.e. [HTTP Raw Request](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RawRequest/) sampler.

If you need extended functionality, i.e. to be able to build requests from text and perform [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) of responses you will have to use the code from [WCF-Binary-SOAP-Plug-In](https://github.com/GDSSecurity/WCF-Binary-SOAP-Plug-In) in [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and perform payload encoding/decoding using [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Hi, late to this thread. Are there any examples of what you've suggested above? Thanks